# PHP - рекурсивный поиск файлов по имени и добавление строки в файл

Tags: php

Привет!
Моя задача:
Сделать скрипт, который будет:

1. Рекурсивно искать файлы по имени, например, `text.txt`.
2. Выводить список с адресом каждого найденного файла
3. Предоставлять возможность выбрать все или некоторые из этих файлов.
4. В выбранные файлы добавлять одну строку.

Я нуб, но не жду готового кода, было бы просто здорово если бы кто-то ткнул носом в то, какие функции лучше всего могли бы подойти и что почитать. 
Пока умею добавлять строку в файл, без проблем, с помощью:

```
$filepathname = "./test.txt";
$target = "A line after which the code should be added";
$newline = "A new line";

$stats = file($filepathname, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);   
$offset = array_search($target,$stats) + 1;
array_splice($stats, $offset, 0, $newline);   
file_put_contents($filepathname, join("\n", $stats));
```

Проблема пока с поиском файлов и возможностью выбора. Код который использую сейчас:

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
glob_recursive($dir);

function glob_recursive($dir){
    foreach(glob($dir."*", GLOB_NOSORT) as $filename){
        if(is_dir($filename)){
            glob_recursive($filename."/*");
        }
        else {
            foreach(glob($dir."test.txt", GLOB_NOSORT) as $filename){
                echo $filename."<br>";
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Выводит результат больше одного раза.

За любую информацию, которая может помочь - спасибо и плюс в карму :)

Comment: В чем же конкретно проблема?

Comment: а где фильтрация `.` и `..`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#97228